# What happens if I send longer key to mysql AES_ENCRYPT than allowed

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

In mysql 5.7.10 I am using AES_Encrypt with cbc 256 bit mode so I have to use 32-byte key. But I I use longer key, the result is different, so how does MYSQL takes longer key into account?

Because I wanted to use 64-byte (512 bit) key and this kind of "works" in MYSQL, but using Chilkasoft crypt2library the 64-byte key is not working, I mean result is not the same as from MySQL.

Any ideas, can I use longer key than 32-byte (I use SHA512 to generate the key, that is why I have 64-byte key).

Answer (score 0):

```
bzero((char*) rkey,AES_KEY_LENGTH/8);
for (ptr= rkey, sptr= key; sptr < key_end; ptr++,sptr++)
{
    if (ptr == rkey_end)
    ptr= rkey;  /*  Just loop over tmp_key until we used all key */
    *ptr^= (uint8) *sptr;
}
```

I found the answer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4863/mysql-aes-encrypt-key-length). Basically it creates an array of zeros and foreach the key and just xors it. No matter how long is the key, the array will be always 32/16 bytes.