# How to implement mysql's HEX AES_ENCRYPT in python?

Tags: python, mysql, encryption, aes

I want to implement mysql's HEX AES_ENCRYPT in python.

```
SELECT HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('C01234567','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ')) AS 'aes_hex'
```

> aes_hex = 'FD6D58DE1D041440097C861ACFED3391'

I wrote the following python code.

```
import hashlib
import binascii
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad

class AESCipher(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode('utf-8')).digest()[:16] # 76fa61caba32baf5715b844a097fb6d5
        # self.key = hashlib.sha1(key.encode('utf-8')).digest()[:16] # a1027e07ad038d4a6d46737692c78a1a

    def encrypt(self, message):
        message = message.encode()
        message = pad(message, 16)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_ECB)
        enc = cipher.encrypt(message)
        return binascii.hexlify(enc).decode('utf-8')
    

key = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ' # length = 17byte
message = 'C01234567'

aes = AESCipher(key)
encrypt = aes.encrypt(message).upper()
print("MYSQL_ : FD6D58DE1D041440097C861ACFED3391")
print("RESULT :", encrypt, "\n")
```

> MYSQL_ : FD6D58DE1D041440097C861ACFED3391

> RESULT : 301CFF9B740A7B0A683D45F98177C060

If a 16byte encryption key is used, the same encryption value as the mysql.
But, if a use a more than 16byte (here 17 byte = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ') the value will be different.

Mysql seems to have a logic to change the key to 16 digits.
(I implemented it like this, but result isn't same...)

> hashlib.sha256(key.encode('utf-8')).digest()[:16]

How should I fixed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of an invalid AES key or an unsupported AES key size, a key derivation function is applied (s. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46812216)) which works as follows:

- Create a target key `derived_key`, initially consisting of `0x00` values, with the required `key_size` (here 16 bytes, since AES-128 is used by default).
- Iterate over the initial key `initial_key` (here `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ`) and XOR target and initial key modulo `key_size`:

```py
def derive_key(initial_key, key_size):
    derived_key = bytearray(b'\0' * key_size)
    for index, value in enumerate(initial_key):
        derived_key[index % key_size] ^= value
    return derived_key
```

`derived_key` for the posted parameters is hex encoded: `1042434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f50`.

Proof:

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad
...
message = b'C01234567'
initial_key = b'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ'
key_size = 16
key = derive_key(initial_key, key_size)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
padded_message = pad(message, AES.block_size)
ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(padded_message)
print("Derived key (hex): " + key.hex())        # Derived key (hex): 1042434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f50
print("Ciphertext (hex) : " + ciphertext.hex()) # Ciphertext (hex) : fd6d58de1d041440097c861acfed3391
```

which provides the required ciphertext.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem I've been struggling with for 2 days has been resolved.